# vaadin submenu code for views

Tags: menu, view, vaadin, submenu

Hi i m added the File menu item creating the views, my code look like

```
final Class viewClass : new Class[] { Dashboard.class,
Editor.class, Ticket.class, MockupView.class }) {
navigator.addView(viewClass.getSimpleName(), viewClass);
menu.addItem(viewClass.getSimpleName(), new MenuBar.Command() {

public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
navigator.navigateTo(viewClass);
}
});
```

but how to add sub menu item inside this menu, any one can help me if you provide me example it will be great full for me

Answer (score 3):

menu.addItem returns a reference to the new menu item, which you can then use to add child items:

```
MenuBar.MenuItem item = menu.addItem("Parent", null);
item.addItem("Child", null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Replay I got the out Put

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is on this [Vaadin documentation page](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.menubar.html)